# Prove that $P(E,X|\hat{X})=P(E|\hat{X})P(X|E,\hat{X})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I would like to prove that $P(E,X|\hat{X})=P(E|\hat{X})P(X|E,\hat{X})$ where $X$,$\hat{X}$ and $E$ are three (not necessarily independent) RVs.

I tried to use Bayes' rule and the chain rule in the following manner:

$$P(E,X|\hat{X})=\frac{P(E,X,\hat{X})}{P(\hat{X})}=\frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{P(\hat{X})}P(X|\hat{X})P(E|X,\hat{X})}{\require{cancel}\cancel{P(\hat{X})}}=P(X|\hat{X})P(E|X,\hat{X})$$

But I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: If you switch $X$ with $E$ in the last line, don't you get the desired desult? The left hand-side does not change if you switch names..

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's simply $P(\hat{X})P(E|\hat{X})P(X|E,\hat{X})$. How stupid! Thanks!